# Typescript 'keyof' keyword makes error when using with react setState function

Tags: typescript

I'm coding Simple LoginForm with react and typescript.

```
interface State {
    username: string;
    password: string;
}

class LoginForm extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    readonly state: Readonly<State> = {
        username: '',
        password: ''
    }

    onChange = (key: keyof State) => (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const value = e.currentTarget.value;
        this.setState({ [key]: value });  // error
    }

    render() {
        return (
            ...
            <TextField
                ...
                onChange={this.onChange('username')}
            />
            <TextField
                ...
                onChange={this.onChange('password')}
            />
            ...
        )
    }
}
```

Typescript failed to compile in setState line with is error.

> Argument of type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'State | ((prevState: Readonly, props: Props) => State | Pick'.
>       Property 'username' is missing in type '{ [x: string]: string; }'.

The 'key' parameter in this.onChange function only allows either 'username' or 'password' as I expected. This means that typescript knows
typeof 'key' parameter must be either 'username' or 'password'. This is obvious because I defined it as (key: key of State).

But why in setState function, typeof 'key' parameter changes to just normal string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have run into a [known TypeScript bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948) where a computed property of a union type is widened to an index signature.  It *looks* like this will be [fixed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21070) for TypeScript 3.0, but that's not certain.

The workaround you should use for now is just to [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) that the object is of the expected type:

```
this.setState({ [key]: value } as Record<typeof key, typeof value>);
```

I'm not familiar enough with React to know if `setState()` is expecting a full `State`, but be warned that `{ [key]: value }` is a `Partial<State>` since it won't contain both keys... and TypeScript won't catch this because `key` is a union type.  So be careful at runtime.  You might want to do the assertion as

```
this.setState({ [key]: value } as Partial<State>);
```

and if that causes an error, it is a real error you should fix.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. You save my time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
onChange = (key: keyof IState) => (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    this.setState({
      [key]: event.currentTarget.value
    } as Pick<IState, keyof IState>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this as an alternative as this solved my issue.

It seems that when setting the state `this.setState({prop: value})` React TS can sometimes expect the full `state`as speculated by @jcalz on the selected answer.

```
this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      [key]: value
});
```

More information about best practices regarding this issue here:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/26635